# How to make the current element toogle, instead of getting the toggle all element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three checboxes of div type and i am bale to toggle them but instead of clicking on any of the one all the checboxes are getting toogled. I want to toggle the selected element only.

```
 My code are as follows:

CSS
====

.outer-box {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ea5700;
  padding:1px;
  width:55px;
  height:23px;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 2px #888888;
}

  .inner-box {
  transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;
  width:15px;
  height:20px;
  margin-right:-2px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display:block;
  right: -32px;
  padding: 4px 5px 3px 3px;
  position: relative;
  border:none;
  border-radius:2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
  }

  #right-box .inner-box {
    left: 37px;
  top: 0;
  }

.txt{
 padding:2px;
  /*font-family:'Roboto Slab', serif;*/
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:;
  color:white;
 }

 #right-box .txt {
 float: left;
 }

  #left-box .inner-box {
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;

 }

 #left-box .txt {
  float: right; 
 }


JS 
 ===

 $(function() {

    $('.outer-box').click(function () {
    var value = $('.outer-box').attr('id');
    if (value === 'right-box') {
        $('.txt').text('NO');
        $('.txt').css('color','grey');
        $('.outer-box').attr('id', 'left-box');
        $('.outer-box').css('background','#e2e2e2');
    } else if (value === 'left-box') {
        $('.txt').text('Yes');
        $('.txt').css('color','white');
        $('.outer-box').attr('id', 'right-box');
        $('.outer-box').css('background','#ea5700');
    }
  });
```

here below is my html code in which i have created the three div elements

```
HTML
====
  <div class="outer-box" id="right-box">
   <div class="txt" style="display:inline;">Yes</div>
     <div class="inner-box"></div>
  </div>

   <div class="outer-box" id="right-box">
   <div class="txt" style="display:inline;">Yes</div>
     <div class="inner-box"></div>
  </div>

 <div class="outer-box" id="right-box">
   <div class="txt" style="display:inline;">Yes</div>
     <div class="inner-box"></div>
  </div>
```

here if i select the any of the checboxes all getting toogle instead i want to toggle the current object which has been clicked. i have used 'This' keyword too but in vain.

Comment: *"here if i select the any of the checboxes all getting toogle..."* How? What's toggling them? How can we help you figure out why that's not working if you don't show it?

Comment: __IDs must be unique__ if you use duplicate ID then your document is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target `.txt` elements with proper context:

```
$('.outer-box').click(function () {

    var value = this.id,
        $txt = $(this).find('.txt');

    if (value === 'right-box') {
        $txt.text('NO').css('color', 'grey');
        $(this).attr('id', 'left-box');
        $(this).css('background', '#e2e2e2');
    } 
    else if (value === 'left-box') {
        $txt.text('Yes').css('color', 'white');
        $(this).attr('id', 'right-box');
        $(this).css('background', '#ea5700');
    }
});
```

Inside click handler select corresponding `.txt` element only with `$(this).find('.txt')` and currently clicked `.outer-box` with `$(this)`.

Also note that you have duplicated ids in HTML, you should fix it by using classes for example instead.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tUbem/

Comment: yeah, It was superb now got the exact working of this keyboard. Now it will help me in future. I think this one can be used by anybody to make thier this keyword concept clear. Thanks dude @dfsq